# How to remove a CDI session scoped bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi

I have a CDI bean defined as following:

```
@Named("loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {
    @EJB
    private LoginManager loginManager;

    private String username;
    private String password;
```

Now I want to remove it from session scope programmatically:

```
HttpSession session = (HttpSession)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false);
LoginBean ins = (LoginBean)session.getAttribute("loginBean");
```

But the `ins` variable is always null. How can I retrieve `loginBean` instance and destroy it?

Comment: Also, canonical link regarding scopes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031885/how-to-choose-the-right-bean-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot safely destroy a CDI bean without breaking something. It is supposed to be destroyed automatically when its context ends (in this case when the session is expired or invalidated).
If you want destruction to happen earlier narrow the scope down to `ConversationScoped` (and set its boundaries) or `ViewScoped` ([available in JSF 2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/ViewScoped.html), the bean will be destroyed when a user navigates to another view).